# Need help to write Excel formula in to SQL condition query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help to write below excel condition in SQL.

```
=IF(OR(C9="",D9=""),"",IF(C9>0,D9-0.00005,D9+0.00005))
```

Now Need write in sql

```sql
where 
C9==>(case when TCLASS<>3 and INDBS=83 then (DP)when TCLASS<>3 and INDBS=66 then (DPS)end )AS C1
D9==> DRATE
```

Comment: That Excel expression looks like something that should be in the `SELECT` not the `WHERE`.

Comment: =IF(OR(C9="",D9=""),"",IF(C9>0,D9-0.00005,D9+0.00005))  this my excel formula in this C9 in my query column name ((case when TCLASS<>3 and INDBS=83 then (DP)when TCLASS<>3 and INDBS=66 then (DPS)end )AS C1) and D9 Column name is DRate.

Comment: Providing a minimal reproducible example would help, such as including a sample of your data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output this condition in a select, it will be as follows:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(C9 ,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(D9 ,0) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN C9 > 0 THEN D9-0.00005
    ELSE D9+0.00005
    END AS FieldName
FROM table
```

Comment: I suspect this is going to error. Firstly, it's implied that `D9` is a `decimal` value, and `''` isn't a valid `decimal` value, so `ISNULL(D9 ,'')` and `THEN ''` would result in conversion errors. Also there's no need for a nested `CASE` expression here, you could just use a second `WHEN`.

Comment: Yes, this helps me, can we write using IF condition this ?? O/P i got is correct  1.063324
1.063352
1.063324
1.063324
1.063352
1.063352
1.063324

Comment: You could `IIF`s, @sathishkumarGuggilla, but I would suggest a single `CASE` expression is cleaner here.

Comment: @Larnu I modified the code